# Create and append CSV row by row

Tags: python, csv, file

I would just like to create a csv file and at the same time add my data row by row with a for loop.

```py
for x in y:
    newRow = "\n%s,%s\n" % (sentence1, sentence2)
    with open('Mydata.csv', "a") as f:
        f.write(newRow)
```

After the above process, I tried to read the csv file but I can't separate the columns. It seems that there is only one column, maybe I did something wrong in the csv creation process?

```py
colnames = ['A_sentence', 'B_sentence']
Mydata = pd.read_csv(Mydata, names=colnames, delimiter=";")
print(Mydata['A_sntence']) #output Nan
```

Comment: You are using commas `','` as delimiters when creating the file, but semi-colons `';'` when reading the file.

Comment: you are right, can i change delimiters during its opening?

Comment: You can set the `delimiter` argument in `pandas.read_csv` to match the actual delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing the file, it looks like you are using commas as separators, but when reading the file you are using semicolons (probably just a typo). Change `delimiter=";"` to `delimiter=","` and it should work.